# C# Make Task Threads Foreground

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, threadpool

I am using Task to create and perform some operations by a different thread, once the operation is done I also have called back to be called.

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                   this._httpService.CreateRecord(new Uri(Configuration.Current.CreateRecordUrl), httpObj)).ContinueWith(
                   (response) =>
                   {
                       if (!response.IsFaulted)
                       {
                           if (httpObj.CallBack != null)
                           {
                               httpObj.CallBack(response.Result);
                           }
                       }
                       else {
                           this._logger.Error("There was some error which causes the task to fail");


                       }
                   });
```

My console application's main thread is not waiting for the Task thread to complete, because it's background thread.
How can I make task thread **foreground thread**?

Thanks

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish? If it's just waiting for the result, why not just use *await*?

Comment: @Robba If i use await then my main thread will be blocked, which i don't want,

Comment: But you're saying that the main thread is not **waiting** for the task to complete. When a thread is waiting, it's automatically blocked. So my question is, if you want to wait without blocking, what exactly is the behavior you're expecting?

Answer (score 4):

[`StartNew()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns a `Task` instance. Calling [`Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the returned task will block the main thread until the task finishes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // ...
    });
    task.Wait(); // The main application thread waits here until the task returns
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> My console application's main thread is not waiting for the Task thread to complete, because it's background thread.

Your application is not waiting for the task, because you don't tell it to do so.

As others have already stated, use `Wait`/`Result` or `await` to wait for the task, depending on whether you're in an asynchronous context or not.

> How can i make task thread foreground thread.

Most likely you don't want to do that in the first place. A *background* thread is a thread that terminates when all *foreground* threads have ended. Thread pool threads are inherently *background* threads, if you actually want to schedule your task to a *foreground* thread, that is, a thread that will keep the app process alive even if the main thread is finished, you'll have to create your own `TaskScheduler`. That, btw, would be a reason to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. If you don't *need* `Task.Factory.StartNew`, go for `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 2):

You should wait for completion of the Task in your main thread.

Change your code to

```
var task =  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    this._httpService.CreateRecord(new Uri(Configuration.Current.CreateRecordUrl), httpObj)).ContinueWith(
        (response) =>
        {
            if (!response.IsFaulted)
            {
                if (httpObj.CallBack != null)
                {
                    httpObj.CallBack(response.Result);
                }
            }
            else {
                this._logger.Error("There was some error which causes the task to field");
            }
        });
task.Wait();  // Wait till your Task has finished.
```

The Wait() method has some overloads to specify how long to wait. Also you have to add some exception handling if Task execution fails due to an exception of cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a fresh new Thread instead of taking from the pool. For eg:

```
Thread t = new Thread(()=> 
{
    //all your code goes here
});
t.IsBackground = false; //by default it will be foreground. so don't need this line in your case
t.Start();
```

This will create a foreground thread for u and it will make sure the thread completes its execution.